# How do I make this else- if statement work by saying in a part of a string isn't equal to a location in the string?

Tags: java, if-statement

The header is :

```
else if(nameOfWebsite.indexOf("http://") == 0 && nameOfWebsite.indexOf("www.") !== 7)
```

the last part of it, `!== 7` how do I make it compile so it still works like how it is supposed to?

Comment: Try `!=` instead of `!==` - there's no `!==` in Java.

Comment: Or, just use the `startsWith` method - `else if (nameOfWebsite.startsWith("http://www.")) {`

Answer (score 2):

- Primtive comparison is done with

  - `o1 == o2` for equality
  - `o1 != o2` for non-equality
- Object comparison is done with

  - `obj1.equals(obj1)` for equality
  - `!obj1.equals(obj1)` for non-equality

---

`===` and `!==` are used in JS

Answer (score 1):

To make the above statement work, you will just need to replace the !== by != as this is the primitive values equality check in Java. Thus, your code will be like this:

```
else if(nameOfWebsite.indexOf("http://") == 0 && nameOfWebsite.indexOf("www.") != 7)
```

From your code statement, it looks like you are trying to validate and possibly extract the value of a site URL. I would suggest using Regex APIs to perform the same function above especially if you have optional `www` in the URL. The code would look like the following:

```
String pattern = "^(http://|https://)?(www.)?([a-z0-9]+)(.[a-z0-9]+)$";
if(nameOfWebsite.matches(pattern)){
   // the rest of the code goes here
}
```

If you would like to extract snippets of the URL, then you should have a look at the `Pattern` class in Java.

Hope this helps.